# Cant configure NAT in iptables

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, port, port-forwarding

Есть два сервера с линукс. Первый выполняет роль роутера, он имеет два сетевых интерфейса, один из которых подключен к интернету, другой к локальной сети. Второй сервер подключен к локальной сети. Задача настроить роутер так, что бы второй сервер имел выход в интернет и был доступен из интернета.

На роутере применял такие правила:

I have 2 servers with linux. Fisrt server is router, it hase eth1, which connected to internet, and eth2 which connected to local network. Second server hase only interface, which connected to local network. I need to make so that the second server had Internet access.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

where eth1 - interface connected to internet, eth2 - interface connected to local network.

```
# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

In local network i can ping both serners. But cant do ping google.com on second server.

Comment: Did you enable forwarding (`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`) in `/etc/sysctl.conf`?

Comment: Not being able to ping google.com may mean a DNS resolution error. What happens if you `ping 8.8.8.8` instead ? If that works, then your setup is correct but you're lacking a DNS resolver (use a public one or install Unbound on the router machine)